# Matlab Text mode subscripts too big in axis label (LaTeX interpreter)

Tags: matlab-figure

If I have the axis label $x_\textrm{ABC}$, the ABC is way too big.  I tried $x_\textrm{\scriptsize ABC}$ and $x_\textrm{\tiny ABC}$, but that prevents the LaTeX code from being interpretted (I end up seeing the raw code instead of the formatted math).  How does one shrink the subscript text size when the subscript is a name that needs to be spelled in text mode?

I posted this to [usenet](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/ajgqwd-BtxY) yesterday, but no response so far.

I also tried to modify the text in Acrobat Pro, but I can't actually highlight the individual series of characters (it's the y-axis label).

Finally, I tried to modify it in inkscape, but same problem.

Answer (score 1):

A respondent at the usenet link provided the answer: To use \mathrm instead of \textrm.  It looks *way* better.